# Sequence contains more than one element when having a .Include

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In my application I have an entity called Board. This board has a list of the Column entity.
When I am trying to get a specific Board and include the Columns with EF Core, I am geting the "Sequence contains more than one element." Error.

Get Board function:

```
public async Task<Board?> GetBoardByWorkspaceIdAndBoardIdAsync(WorkspaceId workspaceId, BoardId boardId)
    {
        var result = await dbContext
            .Boards
            .Where(board => board.WorkspaceId == workspaceId && board.Id == boardId)
            .Include(board => board.Columns)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return result;
    }
```

Board class

```
    public BoardId Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    
    public WorkspaceId WorkspaceId { get; }
    public ICollection<Column> Columns { get; protected set; } = new List<Column>();
```

Board configuration

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Board> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Boards");

        builder.HasKey(board => board.Id);
        builder.Property(board => board.Id)
            .HasConversion(
                boardId => boardId.Value,
                value => BoardId.Create(value));

        builder.Property(board => board.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(board => board.WorkspaceId)
            .HasConversion(
                workspaceId => workspaceId.Value,
                value => WorkspaceId.Create(value))
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasMany(board => board.Columns)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(column => column.BoardId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
```

Column class

```
    public ColumnId Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public BoardId BoardId { get; }
```

Column configuration

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Column> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Columns");

        builder.HasKey(column => column.Id);
        builder.Property(column => column.Id)
            .HasConversion(
                columnId => columnId.Value,
                value => ColumnId.Create(value));

        builder.Property(column => column.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();
    }
```

the migration and updating the database goes fine, but when fetching the Board I get the error. When I remove the include, everything works fine.

Anybody has an idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How EF Core should feed  `Columns` if you specified readonly property?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF Core uses the Public List<Column> navigation property

Comment: But that property should be a list instance that EF populates and returns. Not `_columns.ToList()` which is a new instance all the time.

Comment: @RyanHouben, please include full callstack of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
private readonly List<Column> _columns = new List<Column>();
public List<Column> Columns => _columns.ToList();
```

with this:

```
public ICollection<Column> Columns { get; protected set; } = new List<Column>();
```

When using collection navigation properties you don't want to expose setters but allow EF to initialize and set them up. You can use backing fields but it must be a straight passthrough, no additional `.ToList()` calls which produce new one-off references.

When EF tries to load the columns, it will be attempting to use the Columns property which won't work. Alternatively you could configure EF to use the backing field (_columns) but then the Columns property would need to be marked as `[NotMapped]` and cannot be used in query expressions.

Edit:

So if you update the method to:

```
public async Task<Board?> GetBoardByWorkspaceIdAndBoardIdAsync(WorkspaceId workspaceId, BoardId boardId)
{
    var boardAlone = DbContext.Boards
        .Where(board => board.WorkspaceId == workspaceId && board.Id == boardId)
        .FirstOrDefault();


    var boardAndColumns = DbContext.Boards
        .Include(board => board.Columns)
        .Where(board => board.WorkspaceId == workspaceId && board.Id == boardId)
        .FirstOrDefault();


    var result = await dbContext
        .Boards
        .Where(board => board.WorkspaceId == workspaceId && board.Id == boardId)
        .Include(board => board.Columns)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return result;
}
```

Then "boardAlone" will be loaded and an exception will occur loading "boardAndColumns"? If so, then please include the full exception callstack, that is a very odd issue. Try adding:

```
    var columns = DbContext.Columns
        .Where(column => column.BoardId == boardId)
        .ToList();
```

... and see if that executes or produces a different exception.

One question, why is the board retrieved using both WorkspaceId and BoardId, rather than just BoardId if BoardId is the PK?

Comment: I still gives the same error.

Comment: Is the column ID unique across all columns in the table? Please update the answer to include the updated code for the board class after the above change was applied.

Comment: Updated the code in the question, all column ids are unique in the database.

Comment: Hmm, the exception doesn't marry up with possible configuration issues, not that I see any config issues, though I am not that well versed in custom key types. The exception points at a call to `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()` somewhere, though your example is a `FirstOrDefault()` and on the Boards which wouldn't be impacted if Columns are excluded. Edited above for something to try: